# Javascript Popup Window - Not Opening in Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This works on many clients computers, but I have a user who has this popup open in a full window and does not open in separate window... She is using the latest Google Chrome browser. I want the window to open separately.

HTML

```
 <a onclick='return PopWindow(this.href, this.target);' target='_blank' href='abc.php'>CLICK HERE</a>
```

and then the javascript...

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function PopWindow(url, win) 
 { 
 var w = window.open(url, win, "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=300,height=425,top=50,left=50,location=no").focus();

 return false;
 }
```

Any idea this window opens on some, but not on others. It seems like the dimensions are being ignored...

Comment: Remove the target='_blank' first ?

Comment: Popup behaviour is unreliable across all devices and platforms. Far better to move to a dialog popup-style approach.

Comment: There are a lot of browser security settings which affect how and when a popup will be allowed to be shown. As such you really shouldn't be using them. There are a lot of much better approaches these days

Comment: Does it have to be a new window? Or can you load the content as an overlay div with an iFrame?